# Heat and the Temperature?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have two chambers, one with oil and another with water. They are 1 kg each. When I supply an energy of 33600 J. Find the temperature that oil and water get heated to ?

Specific heat capacity of oil = 2100 
Specific heat capacity of water = 4200

Both are heated from zero degree celsius.

Now I kept these two chambers separated by a conducting wall.

What will be the temperature of both the chambers now ? (Include the steps)
And the energy each carry ?

Comment: What is the specific heat capacity of the oil? What are the starting temperatures of the two liquids?

Comment: What has the zeroth law to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I need answers with proper validity as zeroth law explains to us.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your response. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: I couldnt find the mechanism of heat exchange between two different systems explained in the zeroth law.

Comment: Suppose we are heating oil and water, separately, each of having 1 kg mass. Since the specific heat capacities are different. The water will have lower temperature and the oil will have the higher temperature since we have given equal amount of heat. Now, to where does the heat flow from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the exact answer would require more information, in general, we can answer that:

1. The heat will flow from the higher temperature system to the lower temperature system. As we know the two systems do have different specific heats, then heat must flow.
2. This question is still ill-defined, as it does not specify which temperature, but the temperature of warmer system will decrease, the temperature of the cooler system will increase, and the equilibrium temperature of the two systems together will be the same, and be between their temperatures after heating.

Exact answers will require exact numbers.

Comment: Suppose we are heating oil and water each of having 1 kg mass. Since the specific heat capacities are different. The water will have lower temperature and the oil will have the higher temperature since we have given equal amount of heat. Now, to where does the heat flow from ?

Comment: Heat must flow from the body with higher temperature to the body with lower temperature, so the heat flows from the oil to the water.

Comment: how can the heat flow in contradiction to the concentration gradient ?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I do not see how that is in contradiction to the concentration gradient. Where is the conc. gradient arising? The two systems shouldn't be mixing as that completely changes the nature of the problem.

Comment: its ok. Here i could nt figure out what actually attains equilibrium. now its clear that irrespective of concentration the system attains equal temperature.. Let me know whether i am right. I made a mistake of heat concentration by misconception.

Comment: You are correct, the system will attain thermal equilibrium.